# Date discrepancy between today's The Overflow Blog article and its comments?

Tags: support, time, the-overflow

I was reading an article featured today on The Overflow Blog titled [Best practices for writing code comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/23/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments/) that has today's publication timestamp... when I noticed the comments underneath the article are dated from July!

So this discrepancy in the dates is confusing. Can someone explain to me how I should determine the original date of publication or if this is an unintended bug or side-effect?

[image: screenshot the overflow blog best practices for writing code comments]

[image: screenshot comments underneath blog article]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the article, there's an editor note:

> [Ed. note: While we take some time to rest up over the holidays and prepare for next year, we are re-publishing our top ten posts for the year. Please enjoy our favorite work this year and we'll see you in 2022.]

which indicates that the article is not new. I was able to find [the original one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210716145058/https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/05/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments/) on Web Archive and it looks like it was posted on July 5, 2021:

[image: original article publish date]

Its URL (`https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/05/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments`) now redirects to `https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/23/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments`.